# Modal box not showing in ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

Modal box opening issue in ionic 4. Does not open at all and there is no error too. Need help.

I am writing a hybrid android app using ionic 4. In earlier versions of ionic it was easy to open modal box. I am facing modal box opening issue in ionic 4 now.  ModalController is also imported and controller is also configured correctly.

controller

```
constructor(private nav: NavController, public http: Http, public modalCtrl: ModalController) {}
```

Modal opening code

```
async openModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: GRPSearchModalPage
    });

    await modal.present();
}
```

Below is the complete code from GRPSearchModalPage

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams, ModalController  } from '@ionic/angular';
@Component({
selector: 'app-grpsearch-modal-page',
templateUrl: './grpsearch-modal-page.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./grpsearch-modal-page.component.scss']
})

export class GRPSearchModalPageComponent implements OnInit 
{
  constructor( private navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl:
  ModalController ) { }

ngOnInit() { }

closeModal() {
 this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
}
}
```

Comment: Make sure **GRPSearchModalPage** is declared inside your *NgModule*, and check if your function `openModal` is called.

Comment: Hi @StephanStrate thanks for your help. I've GRPSearchModalPage declared inside NgModule too. openModal() method is also called. I tried adding console.log() as first statement to print some text to confirm it too. Not able to display modal box.

Comment: How did you declared GRPSearchModalPage? Try to add a bit more context to your question

Comment: I create this modal page as component using command ionic generate component GRPSearchModalPage.   And in app.module.ts I added required import statement and then also inside @NgModule({ })

Comment: Sounds good, just add more code snippets to your question, please. For example a snippet of you adding GRPSearchModalPage to NgModule

Comment: I have been trying and checking several websites on ionic tutorials but to success. Will dig further. Thanks for your time sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: I have the same issue too, nobody managed to find a solution for this yet?

Comment: I think the answer below will help you. Make sure you check the app.module.ts file inside the src/app directory.

Answer (score 1):

After importing the component in the app.module.ts make sure to add it to both the **declarations** and the **entryComponents** arrays.

**app.module.ts**

```
...

import { GRPSearchModalPageComponent } from 'YOUR_COMPONENT_DIRECTORY';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, GRPSearchModalPageComponent],
  entryComponents: [GRPSearchModalPageComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I usually forget to add it to the entryComponents array.